# SQLite Alternative for higher concurrent transactions

Tags: sqlite, concurrency, sql-server-express

Can anyone suggest a light weight database that is better suitable for concurrent connections?  I will be constantly updating / inserting / deleting rows from my table on multiple threads, so I need something that can handle this.  The db is extremely small. Only 2 tables, one with 3 columns and 150 rows that only update, and a 2nd table with 2 columns and a max of 15,000 rows that are constantly being inserted, pulled / removed, then new data inserted once table becomes to small (a basic queue).

The logic of this would call for SQLite because it is so lightweight, however the fact that I am doing the calls on 50+ threads is basically killing my performance because SQLite's locking.  All of my threads are waiting for each other, basically making threading pointless after about 20.

I would really like to avoid installing a full copy of say mySQL or SQL server, if I could.  I am hoping for a better solution, though if that is the case, I will do it. (Anyone know if SQL Express 4 is better for this?)

I am currently developing in the .net framework 4.0 using SQLite.net and an entity 4.0 model, though this question should work and apply to any language, since SQLite is widely used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What SQLite pragmas do you have? What is your journal-mode? WAL?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in sqlite's bad locking? It is possible you're suffering penalty from too much context switching and no other database will be able to perform better. 50+ threads are quite many, consider reducing this number.

Comment: ham: I have gotten way better performance on true database servers with this issue at hand already. I am avoiding this if I can.

Comment: benoit: it is currently set to delete, which was the default set in SQLite.net editor

Comment: also another reason I know this, hamstergene, is because I can insert 10,000 rows in 2-3 seconds in mySQL, where as SQLite on the same computer could take over a minute.  =/

Comment: Benoit: I am trying WAL now to see if it changes. Was not aware there were different.

Answer (score 0):

Besides MS SQL Express that you've already mentioned, there is [Firebird embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) database server, maybe it will perform better than SQLite for your use cases.

Or, consider reducing number of threads, or queue queries manually using custom locking / message passing. Switching away from the fastest option just because your current code misuses the library doesn't seem quite right to me.

Comment: If I would be queuing the requests, it basically defeats the purpose of what I am doing this for. I was holding all this information in memory, but lost it each time I close. Reason I removed this is so I can keep a "State" between app loads easily. However, adding an in memory queue is taking me back to square 1 (and really in my mind a job of the database)